# Reading file content opened with ifstream

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a problem reading file, opened with fstream on windows.

```
std::ifstream file(file_name);
if(!file.is_open()){
  std::cerr <<  "file cannot be opened";
}
if (!file){
  std::cerr << "errors in file";
}   

std::vector<std::string> strings;
std::string str;
while (std::getline(file, str)) {
  strings.push_back(str);
}
```

File opened sucessfully and it has no errors, but cycle with getline gets no content.

Besides this sample runs perfect and prints whole file content

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(file), std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cerr, "\n"));
```

On linux everything is perfect, same file, same code, getline in cycle reads all.

Visual Studio 2013

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that i have this little line of code before cycle with getline

```
std::cout << file.rdbuf();
```

On linux this line just prints file content, on windows it not only print, but makes file inacessible to `std::getline`

Comment: So after the while loop if you print `strings.size()` you get zero?

Comment: @NathanOliver yep

Comment: Is the file a text file?  Is the first character 0x1A?  In Windows, there are special character or byte values that indicate an end of file condition.  If your file contains these at the beginning *and you don't open the file as binary*, Windows OS will return an end of file condition.

Answer (score 3):

`getline()` extracts characters from the input stream until either  newline character is reached or `delim` which is also a character, but instead of only extracting, getline discards the deliminating character. Check your file to see if you started with a `newline character`, meaning in the file you started on a line other than the first one. If so,

```
while (std::getline(file, str)) {
  strings.push_back(str);
}
```

would always `iterate only 1 time`, returning no characters because it only discarded the newline character.

```
while (std::getline(file, str) || !file.eof) {
  strings.push_back(str);
}
```

Will now, if it runs into a `deliminating character`, also check if the end of the file has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in calling

```
std::cout << file.rdbuf();
```

before `while(std::getline)`
on Windows this line makes file not accessible to std::getline

Comment: What was the reason behind calling it?